# Efficient computation of the dot product of a matrix, which is a chain of Kronecker products, and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

The problem is this:

I need to compute $U.v$ where $v$ is a $2^6$ dimensional vector and $U$ is a chain of Kronecker products of $6$ $2\times2$ matrices.

That is I need to compute

$$U.v = (U_1\otimes U_2\otimes U_3\otimes U_4\otimes U_5\otimes U_6).v$$

I could not find a relevant property of such a product form so any computational advice will also be appreciated.

The matrices $U_i$ all are drawn from the set of Pauli matrices if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\vec{\textsf{vec}}\newcommand\reshape{\textsf{reshape}}$You should read Section 1.3.7 from Golub and Van Loan's book *Matrix Computations*. In particular, this question is a special case of their exercise P1.3.9:

> Suppose $A^{(k)}\in \mathbb{R}^{n_k \times n_k}$ for $k=1,\ldots,r$ and that $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $n = n_1\cdots n_r$. Give an efficient algorithm for computing $y = (A^{(r)}\otimes \cdots \otimes A^{(2)}\otimes A^{(1)})x$.

The solution relies on the equality $$Y = C X B^T \iff \vec(Y) = (B\otimes C)\vec(X),$$ where $\vec(X)$ is the (linear) map that stacks the columns of a matrix from left-to-right into a long vector. In particular, $$y = (A^{(r)}\otimes \cdots \otimes A^{(1)})x \iff \reshape(y,\tfrac{n}{n_r},n_r) = (A^{(r-1)}\otimes \cdots\otimes A^{(1)})\reshape(x,\tfrac{n}{n_r},n_r)(A^{(r)})^\mathsf{T}$$ where $\reshape(A,m,n)$ is the matrix of shape $m\times n$ defined by $\vec(\reshape(A,m,n)) = \vec(A)$. This gives us the following recursive algorithm for this problem:

```
function y = kronmatvec(A[r,...,1], x)
    if r equals 1
         return A[r] * x
    end

    Let n, nr = length(x), shape(A[r])[0]
    Reshape x = reshape(x, n / nr, nr)
    Compute Z = x * transpose(A[r])

    for each column i = 1,2,...,nr
        Compute Y[:,i] = kronmatvec(A[r-1,...,1],Z[:,i])
    end

    return vec(Y)
end
```

To analyze the runtime in floating point operations, assume $n_i = c$ uniformly and write $T(r)$ for the floating point operations used in calling `kronmatvec(A[r,...,1], x)`. Note that $T(1) \leq 2c^2$. In general, $T$ satisfies the recurrence
$$
T(r) \leq 2c^{r+1} + cT(r-1) \quad\text{ which gives }\quad T(r) \leq 2r c^{r+1} = 2\tfrac{c}{\log c}n\log n \text{ flops}.
$$
Naively computing a matrix-vector in this dimension takes on the order of $2 n^2$ flops so this is an immense speedup for large $n$ and $c = o(n)$.

See a Python/NumPy implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/cdipaolo/c32de5828c99e684f0b57e0ce7b5b424) along with runtime benchmarks. This recursive formulation appears to be practically faster once $n > 1000$, and becomes much much faster after that point.

Realistically, since your matrices are of size $2^6 = 64$, the fastest thing to do without significant code optimization is to compute the Kronecker product and matrix product explicitly.

Comment: Great answer. So you are saying this algorithm wouldn't make much of a difference compared to the naive method in my case of 64 dimensions?

Comment: @AbhijeetMelkani Yeah exactly. Your matrices are small enough that doing something naive is likely the fastest thing you can do because “faster” algorithms in terms of floating point operations will likely have enough non-flop overhead to make them slower in practice unless you do a whole lot of code optimization. If you think you’re going to have 10 or more matrices $U_i$, though, you should use this approach or something similar. I suspect if you made this algorithm iterative instead of recursive and moved the computation into Cython, you could get a speed up with something like 7 or 8 $U_i$

Comment: In theory, the flop count of this approach is better as soon as $n>16$ in your case, so in the absence of these nontrivial implementation details it _should_ be faster.